# iOS - Playback of recorded audio fails with OSStatus error -43 (file not found)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I set up an AVAudioRecorder instance the following way when my view loads:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
audioSession.delegate = self;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *soundFilePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.m4a"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
NSLog(@"%@", soundFileURL);

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error = nil;

self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                 initWithURL:soundFileURL
                 settings:recordSettings
                 error:&error];
self.recorder.delegate = self;

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    [self.recorder prepareToRecord];
}
```

Then, when the user presses the record button I do:

```
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender {
    if (!self.isRecording) {
        self.isRecording = YES;
        [self.recorder record];
        self.recordButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Then to stop the recording/playback:

```
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    if (self.isRecording) {
        [self.recorder stop];
        self.recordButton.enabled = YES;
        self.isRecording = NO;
    }

    if (self.isPlaying) {
        [self.player stop];
        self.isPlaying = NO;
        self.playButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

After, I want to be able to playback what was recorded, so I do the following:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.recorder.url error:&error];
    self.player.delegate = self;

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        self.isPlaying = YES;
        [self.player play];
        self.playButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

But when I go and play the file is get **OSStatus error -43** file not found.

This is all running on the device btw, on the simulator y an error when trying to instantiate the recorder or player, and from I've seen it's a simulator issue.

**EDIT 1:** I solved the OSStatus error -43 part it has something to do with the encoding format, I commented out the format and it recorded and played the file properly, but I need to record in a compressed format. Does anyone know the settings for this?

**EDIT 2:** I managed to find settings that worked for compressed AAC audio. A 2min audio file comes out to 256KB, I updated my code to reflect the current state. Thanks to all of those who answered for your help.

Comment: Maybe that file is still in use by the recorder and hence is not available for reading? (just a stab in the dark though)

Comment: I believe that would yield and error in such case, and when I hit stop the recorder stops so I highly doubt that.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm a bit wrong with this as I've hardly used any audio related classes but is there a `[self.player prepareToPlay]`?

Comment: Question: Are you testing on a device or in Simulator? If a device, which one?

Comment: This is on a device, iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1

Comment: When I run your code I get this error after tapping the Record button. <AQConverterThread> aq@0xc240600: ConvertInput: AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer returned 560226676, packetCount 3

And then when you tap stop it gives this: <com.apple.main-thread>   flushing pending input terminated - error '!dat'

And tapping play gives this: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)

I copied your code and have the correct properties set.

Comment: @JoshuaDance: I get the same problem too. The following dictionary settings: `[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:32.0*1000], AVSampleRateKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey, nil];` work for me in the simulator but not on my 4S. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm gonna take a wild stab at this since no-one else has answered (EDIT: now there is) (I don't have much experience with Audio in iOS) but...

Try changing

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
```

to

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

Comment: Yeah, this may prevent the need to change the category back to playback as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Just noticed this, I do set it up to PlayAndRecord in my code, but I set it back to record in my record method (dumb me). Edited my code to reflect the change. Still getting just like white noise.

Comment: Modified it, now I'm getting file not found error. It seems it's not creating the audio file.

Answer (score 2):

`AVEncoderBitRateKey` is not working with `AAC` format encoding.So try this code.

```
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
NSLog(@"%@", soundFileURL);

 NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                        dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],
                                        AVFormatIDKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],
                                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], 
                                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                        AVSampleRateKey,
                                        nil];
NSError *error = nil;

self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                 initWithURL:soundFileURL
                 settings:recordSettings
                 error:&error];
self.recorder.delegate = self;

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
} else {
    [self.recorder prepareToRecord];
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

**OSStatus error -43 file not found** is not a simulator issue. It's an error log, which shows your `recording settings are not correct` and required `encoding format is not supported for the settings you have selected`.

When you get this error, you file will get created in the format as you given. But It will `not initialize your audio recorder to start recording`. If you have any doubt, then select the same settings, which you had in first question and record and try to play that. It won't record and play because of unsupported setting.

So for a `compressed encoding format`, you can use a settings as I given above in my code. You can have `.aac` format for this settings. It will take `164KB per 10 seconds to record in aac` format. For rest of the formats you have to try and figure out.

Comment: I saw your new code.. Your Encoding format is kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC and your extension is .m4a . I thought you need .aac extension file. For that use this code. It will be good.

Comment: I was seeing errors, but just on the simulator.  When I stopped using AVEncoderBitRateKey it worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the AVAudioSession category back to playback mode:

```
NSError *_error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&_error];

if (_error) {
    // handle error here
}
```

This should also avoid the problem where the audio will not play with the mute switch toggled on.

Comment: Edited my code for this, didn't notice I wasn't doing it, now I'm getting OSStatus error -43 (File not found)

Comment: Be carefull, you should test if "setCategory:error: returns YES or NO and not test if error is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this:

Make `NSURL *soundFileURL` global for your class so you can access it anywhere in your class and set in the same way as you are now (except it would be `soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];` instead of `NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];`.

Then change this

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.recorder.url error:&error];
```

to this

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];
```