# In iOS Core Audio - what's the best way of looking up OSStatus errors ( ie -43?)

Tags: ios, core-audio, runtime-error

What's the best way to look up the meaning of **OSStatus** errors ( i.e. **-43** ) in Core Audio? Is there a way to process them in your iOS code so they can be formatted to show up with a brief explanation in the console?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218257/ios-playback-of-recorded-audio-fails-with-osstatus-error-43-file-not-found

Comment: Saw that - lots of stuff about what to do after you know it's a file not found error, not so clear on how to look it up.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other one, finding the error codes is a bit of a constant pain for core audio develeopers.

Answer (score 5):

After a quick look around, the best way so far seems to be to use the Unix command line tool - macerror - and type in the error code as an argument: not sure if it's possible to call & get the results of a macerror query from my Obj-C code in iOS into a console print out.

Comment: hmm, while it's interesting to know about ´macerror´, most of the AudioUnit related errors I get show up as "unknown error", which isn't super helpful. Eg. -10877, -10861, -10860, 2755.

Comment: Crap, I can't find the original page that used to list this stuff ... I'll break it apart and list 'em below.

Comment: CORE MIDI ERRORS

 kMIDIInvalidClient = -10830,
 kMIDIInvalidPort = -10831,
 kMIDIWrongEndpointType = -10832,
 kMIDINoConnection = -10833,
 kMIDIUnknownEndpoint = -10834,
 kMIDIUnknownProperty = -10835,
 kMIDIWrongPropertyType = -10836,
 kMIDINoCurrentSetup = -10837,
 kMIDIMessageSendErr = -10838,
 kMIDIServerStartErr = -10839,
 kMIDISetupFormatErr = -10840,
 kMIDIWrongThread = -10841,
 kMIDIObjectNotFound = -10842,
 kMIDIIDNotUnique = -10843

Comment: TOOLBOX

 kAudioToolboxErr_InvalidSequenceType = -10846,
 kAudioToolboxErr_TrackIndexError = -10859,
 kAudioToolboxErr_TrackNotFound = -10858,
 kAudioToolboxErr_EndOfTrack = -10857,
 kAudioToolboxErr_StartOfTrack = -10856,
 kAudioToolboxErr_IllegalTrackDestination = -10855,
 kAudioToolboxErr_NoSequence = -10854,
 kAudioToolboxErr_InvalidEventType = -10853,
 kAudioToolboxErr_InvalidPlayerState = -10852,
 these are dupes
 kAudioToolboxErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext = -10863
 kAudioUnitErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext = -10863,

Comment: AUDIO UNIT 1

 kAudioUnitErr_InvalidProperty = -10879,
 kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter = -10878,
 kAudioUnitErr_InvalidElement = -10877,
 kAudioUnitErr_NoConnection = -10876,
 kAudioUnitErr_FailedInitialization = -10875,
 kAudioUnitErr_TooManyFramesToProcess = -10874,
 kAudioUnitErr_InvalidFile = -10871,
 kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported = -10868,
 kAudioUnitErr_Uninitialized = -10867,
 kAudioUnitErr_InvalidScope = -10866,

Comment: Audio Unit 2 

 kAudioUnitErr_PropertyNotWritable = -10865,
 kAudioUnitErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext = -10863,
 kAudioUnitErr_InvalidPropertyValue = -10851,
 kAudioUnitErr_PropertyNotInUse = -10850,
 kAudioUnitErr_Initialized = -10849,
 kAudioUnitErr_InvalidOfflineRender = -10848,
 kAudioUnitErr_Unauthorized = -10847

Comment: There's more, but those are the main ones - this page claims to have found the answer, but I couldn't find 'em using his instructions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906111/ios-where-to-find-the-full-list-of-osstatus-codes-for-ios

Comment: Wow :-)  I usually look them up in the corresponding header files: in Xcode you can just cmd+click on the kXxxErr_xxx. The AudioUnit related errors can be found in AUComponent.h

Answer (score 3):

A recent article in [IOS Dev Weekly](https://iosdevweekly.com/) linked to a great webpage that allows you to search for all OSStatus codes. [Definitely worth bookmarking.](http://www.osstatus.com/)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I just noticed that at least one error code (560226676) is actual a four-letter code; it can be represented as '!dat' in big-endian. Searching for that gives kAudioDeviceUnsupportedFormatError.

IOW, it can't hurt to print error codes with a little function like this:

```
char *OSTStr( OSType type )
{
    static union OSTStr {
        uint32_t four;
        char str[5];
    } ltype;
    ltype.four = EndianU32_BtoN(type);
    ltype.str[4] = '\0';
    return ltype.str;
}
```

Comment: And how you resolved this error? I get the same code when I convert m4a to lpcm with AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer.

Comment: This error means you're trying to convert an unsupported format. Quick guess: only two solutions: find other data to convert or find a converter that supports your data...