# Text from error code

Tags: ios, iphone

```
OSStatus status = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, nil);
[NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain code:status userInfo:nil];//not really useful
```

returns an error (-66674). So I am curios what the errors means. But more I really want to know whether there is some better function on iOS which gives me a text for the error like:

```
NSString* errorText = SomeMagicErrorFunction( status );
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the errors are in the documentation (you can search the documentation for 'AudioQueueStart' to find the correct documentation page). it's [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html).

The error is `kAudioQueueErr_PrimeTimedOut` the extra detail is:

> During a call to the AudioQueuePrime function, the audio queue’s audio converter failed to convert the requested number of sample frames.
>   Available in OS X v10.6 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a complete solution.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196869/how-do-you-convert-an-iphone-osstatus-code-to-something-useful/23708500#23708500) I posted an answer with a OSX program you can write that decodes some, but not all, the codes and it relies on Carbon for that purpose (still works under 10.9, but not tested under 10.10).

So the idea is that you log the error codes in your app's log files and when diagnosing the issue from production you use the program I provide to attempt to get some meaningful error text.

Another solution is given in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906111/ios-where-to-find-the-full-list-of-osstatus-codes-for-ios/16906296#16906296), where you search for the error code in the SDK include files in order to find some meaning.

Not ideal, but I guess Apple want it that way.