# AVAudioRecorder not working on iPhone 5S

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

So I'm using an AVAudioRecorder to record audio alongside an AVCaptureSession that is recording video (I know this is odd, but for my situation I need to record them seperately).

Everything works fine on every device, except for my iPhone 5S. It records without error, but the file that is saved to disk is corrupted or something. When I access the file system on my mac and try and play the m4a file with VLC or Quicktime, I get a "format of the file cannot be detected" error. Here is how I am initializing my AVAudioRecorder and recording my audio:

```
// Prepare the audio session
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording error:nil];

 // Setup audio recording
 NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                      AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityLow),
                                      AVEncoderBitRateKey: @16,
                                      AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @1,
                                      AVSampleRateKey: @22050.0f};

 NSError *audioRecorderError;

 NSURL *audioFileURL = [[self.outputFileURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a"];

 self.audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFileURL
                                                              settings:recordSettings
                                            error:&audioRecorderError];

self.audioRecorder.delegate = self;

 if (audioRecorderError) {
      CCLog(@"Error while initializing the audio recorder... Skipping sound recording!");
 }
else {
    if (![self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord]) {
        CCLog(@"Error preparing to record");
    }
    if (![self.audioRecorder record]) {
        CCLog(@"Error recording");
    }
}
```

Again, this works on all devices aside from the 5S. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried a different 5S to make sure its not a problem with your phone or its OS?

Comment: Yes, this happens on every 5S I have tested on.

Comment: Yes, I tried my 5S and it's not working. my iPad2(ios7) iPhone4(IOS7) is working good.  This is really odd.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Did some more digging and I apparently found the solution. I simply got rid of AVEncoderBitRateKey and everything works fine. So now my recordSettings dictionary looks like this:

```
// Setup audio recording
NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityLow),
                                  AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @1,
                                  AVSampleRateKey: @22050.0f};
```

Still not sure why this would be the case only on an iPhone 5S. Again, I've tested on all other devices running iOS6 and iOS7, and the old settings dictionary works fine on everything except for the 5S. Now that I've removed the AVEncoderBitRateKey and value, it also works on the 5S.

Comment: This is pretty disconcerting, it in fact does work to do this but WHY?!

Comment: @Rob I completely agree. I accepted my own response as the answer because it solves the problem. But I agree that I would also love to know why this is the case.

Comment: I'm running into a similar situation, but on a retina iPad mini. If I remove `AVEncoderBitRateKey` OR `AVFormatIDKey` it'll record. If I leave both of those in, it won't. No idea why. I believe this code worked on a 3rd gen iPad. *Maybe* something to do with the 64 bit processor?

Comment: @codyko Thanks a lot. I have a similar problem but exclusively when RecordSound in iPadAir but when removed AVEncoderBitRateKey works perfect. I suppose is must be related about several microphones.

Comment: I have similar problems with iPad Mini Retina and iPhone5S. My code works for simulator and yours too, but none work in any of the 2 devices. I have been trying to play around with the settings, even passing a nil settings but didn't help.

Comment: iOS8, iPhone 6, still relevant

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's actually an interaction between `AVNumberOfChannelsKey` and `AVEncoderBitRateKey`. I can't seem to record above 64000Kbps when the # of channels = 1, but when it = 2, I can use 128000...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem - and the answer proved to be related to AVAudioSession. I needed to set the audio session category to PlayAndRecord. Other parts of my application were setting it to Ambient. This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287793/1009125 gave me the answer. Hope this helps someone, I lost a Sunday to this one.