# After record sound file, this can't heard in iPad Air only

Tags: ipad, ios7, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I have an app in the Apple Store with voice recording capability. I migrate to Xcode 5.0.2 and SDK 7.
I have no problem with this feature in devices with iOS 6 or 7 except with iPad Air.
This is my record Sound routine:

```
+(void) startRecording:(NSString *)fileName :(NSString *)fileType
{   NSError* theError = nil;
BOOL result = YES;

// Init audio with record capability
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
result = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&theError];
if (!result)
{
    NSLog(@"setCategory failed %@", theError);
}
result = [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
if (!result)
{
    NSLog(@"setActive failed %@", theError);
}

// Verify if you have granted to use microphone. iOS 7 or later
if ([audioSession respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)]) {
    [audioSession requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            // Record Sound
            [self recordNow:fileName :fileType];
        }
        else {
            // Microphone disabled code
            NSLog(@"Microphone is disabled..");

            // We're in a background thread here, so jump to main thread to do UI work.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Microphone Access Denied"
                                             message:@"This app requires access to your device's Microphone.\n\nPlease enable Microphone access for this app in Settings / Privacy / Microphone"
                                            delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            });
        }
    }];
}
else {  // iOS 6 
    // Record sound
    [self recordNow:fileName :fileType];
}
}

// Record Sound
+(void) recordNow:(NSString *)fileName :(NSString *)fileType {
recordEncoding = ENC_AAC;

// Microphone enabled code
if (kDebugMode) {
    NSLog(@"Microphone is enabled..");
}

NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
{
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
}
else
{
    NSNumber *formatObject;

    switch (recordEncoding) {
        case (ENC_AAC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ALAC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
            break;
        case (ENC_IMA4):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
            break;
        case (ENC_ILBC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ULAW):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
            break;
        default:
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
    }

    [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey:         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
}

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *recDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", recDir, fileName, fileType]];    
NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];

[audioRecorder recordForDuration:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kRecordForDuration]];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot research inside this site, i found an excellent comment that saves my day here:
["Now that I've removed the AVEncoderBitRateKey and value, it also works on the 5S."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192316/avaudiorecorder-not-working-on-iphone-5s/19438788#19438788)

So, i just comment this row and fix it !!

```
[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
```

I can hear again the record sound in iPad Air ! 
Why happen this? I did not know yet, but its works and maybe you have the same problem and just want to leave a log about this case in this website.