# Unable to play recorded audio

Tags: swift, ios8, tableview, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm not being able to play recorded audio.

- I have TableViewController to manage a Static TableView in which one the static cells contains an embedded Dynamic Table View, whose Delegate and DataSource are assigned to a different class.
- My Dynamic TableView has a custom cell that lists the Title of the recording and has a button which i want to press to play the recorded audio.

The Table views seems to be listing the recordings which I think are working because I'm printing their duration, but when i press the play button nothing seems to happen I don't hear any audio or get any errors.

I believe this situation has already occurred me thus in a different context, when trying to record the audio:

- Since my Dynamic TableView and a record button are both inside a View which I show or hide with a SegmentedControl, it make sense at the time to specify the action for the record button in this view class, who was also the delegate and data source for my Dynamic TableView, what happened was that the recording was successful, I was able to print it's path but the Dynamic TableView didn't update it's content, nor i got any errors. I had than to set the action to the record button in my TableViewController class for the Dynamic Table to update, if i asked (reloadData) to the instance of the class that I've created which by the way was the delegate and data source for my Dynamic Table and contained an outlet to my Dynamic Table it didn't update and no errors.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

---

// MARK: Voice Recorder

```
var recController = RecordingsController()
var audioRec: AudioRecording!
var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
var session: AVAudioSession!
var currentDateTime: String!
let minute : Double = 60.0
var recordingInProgress: Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var recordingsTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var recPlayInProgressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btnStartStopRecordingOutlet: UIButton!           // Starts / Stops Recordings or Playbacks Button Outlet

@IBAction func btnStartStopRecordingAction(sender: UIButton) {

    // Starts / Stops voice recording

    self.toggleAudioRecorder()

    if(self.recordingInProgress){

        // Inits Recording Process
        self.audioRec = AudioRecording()
        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
        self.currentDateTime = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .FullStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
        self.audioRec.name = self.currentDateTime + ".wav"
        var pathArray = [dirPath, self.audioRec.name]
        self.audioRec.filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)

        // Setup audio session
        self.session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        self.session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

        // Initialize and prepare the recorder
        self.recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.audioRec.filePath, settings: nil, error: nil)
        self.recorder.delegate = self
        self.recorder.prepareToRecord()
        self.recorder.record()
    }else{

        // Sets the Recording Title and stops the Recording Process

        (self.recorder.currentTime < self.minute) ? (self.audioRec.title = "[" + (NSString(format:"%.2f", (self.recorder.currentTime)) as String) + "s] " + self.currentDateTime) : (self.audioRec.title = "[" + (NSString(format:"%.2f", (self.recorder.currentTime) / self.minute) as String) + "m] " + self.currentDateTime)

        self.recorder.stop()
        var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        audioSession.setActive(false, error: nil)
    }
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {

    // Save recorded audio

    var recordedAudio = (title: recorder.url.lastPathComponent, filePathUrl: recorder.url)
    println(recordedAudio.filePathUrl)
    self.recController.recordings += [self.audioRec]

    self.recordingsTable.reloadData()
}

func toggleAudioRecorder() {

    // Toogle audio recording

    if(self.recPlayInProgressLabel.text == "playing"){
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Playback in Progress!\nPlease stop the current playback before starting an audio recording.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
            self.recordingInProgress = !self.recordingInProgress
        if(self.recordingInProgress){
            self.btnStartStopRecordingOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "StopIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.recPlayInProgressLabel.text = "recording"
        }else{
            self.btnStartStopRecordingOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "AudioRecIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.recPlayInProgressLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the code to record audio? I have an historical issue with record-play sounds and always finish with the framework that i used or check the path where you are save the record file.

Comment: i'm sorry what do you mean by "always finish with the framework that i used or check the path where you are save the record file"?

Comment: Don't worry, BTW sorry in advance for my english. Print the content of this variable "var pathArray" (i don't know swift yet) and check is correct the complete path and the other thing, check the default value for settings inside AVAudioRecorder (// Initialize and prepare the recorder), because maybe you need modify some settings and not just put nil.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916114/after-record-sound-file-this-cant-heard-in-ipad-air-only is one of the historical problem that I had with Obj-c.